# In Corda, how can I see which responder flows my node has registered?

Tags: corda

As of Corda 3, `CordaRPCOps` provides a `registeredFlows()` method to see which initiating flows my node has installed. However, there is no corresponding method to see which responder flows my node has installed.

How can I check which responder flows my node has installed?

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3, there is no method to return the list of responder flows installed on a node.

However, when the node starts up, it will log a message for each responder flow it installs indicating the responder flow's name and the initiating flow it is registered to respond to. In the node logs, you should see lines like the following:

`[INFO ] 2018-10-24T20:05:42,075Z [main] internal.Node.registerInitiatedFlowInternal - Registered net.corda.traderdemo.flow.SellerFlow to initiate net.corda.traderdemo.flow.BuyerFlow (version 1) {}`